# What does "people reached" mean?

Tags: support, profile-page

I can't elaborate but what does this these words [people reached](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/230533/unique) mean? For example:- 15k people reached.

Comment: General Tip: Meta questions that are not specific to Phys.SE should be asked on the [mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site instead. Check for duplicates!

Answer (score 9):

The people reached, or impact score, is a metric loosely based on how many people have seen your posts (both questions and answers). The [formulation is based on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here):

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

For more details on what the goals of the score are and how this was determined, check out the announcement on the mother Meta site: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)